# Applying font-family to single hyphen does NOT work in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

#### High-level Problem:  CSS font style doesn't apply to a single hyphen within a span

We've run into an odd situation in Wordpress where a very basic CSS font style doesn't work when trying to apply that style to a single hyphen targeted by a span and class.

The HTML is a very straight-forward:

```
<h2>Test<span class="angleHyphen">-</span>Heading</h2>
```

The CSS is also a very straight-forward:

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy');

    span.angleHyphen {
      font-family:'Sorts Mill Goudy', serif;
    }
```

#### The problem is unique to Wordpress

If you run that code in CodePen or in a vanilla HTML page, it will work exactly as you'd expect.  However, it does NOT work when generated by Wordpress' editor - either Guttenberg or visual composer.  If you're going to answer (which I genuinely appreciate), I'd encourage you to test this in any Wordpress environment before replying "It works in this CodePen or Stack snippet".

#### Only a problem when applying to the single hyphen

This appears to be unique to having the hyphen be the only content of the span.  If you expand the span to include the entire heading, the font (including the hyphen) are applied correctly.  In other words, this works (though it doesn't give us the solution we need):

```
<h2><span class="angleHyphen">Test-Heading</span></h2>
```

#### Another approach we tried to test:

Confusing us even more, if we apply the CSS rotate attribute (with browser prefixes), that style applies to the span with the single hyphen.  In other words, the font-family attribute does not work, but we can somewhat emulate the look using other CSS attributes.  Unfortunately for us, the Goudy-based font is a significant part of the client's branding and that work-around has not been accepted.

I've created a live demo of the problem at [wptest.4sdesignstudio.com](http://wptest.4sdesignstudio.com) which also includes some additional notes and examples if you're curious or want to take the time to dig into this.

You'll see that there are no console errors.  If you inspect element, you'll see that the font shows that it's getting applied.  We've included the example listed above where we encase the entire heading in the span - showing that the font is correctly getting loaded through Google Fonts.

#### A few other things we've tried based on yesterdays feedback from Stack (and basic debugging):

- Adding the hyphen using unicode, hex, html code and html entity
- Using !important in the CSS
- Adding the font-weight, both in the @import and as an attribute of .angleHyphen in the CSS (this particular font only has a single font-weight so it shouldn't be necessary, but we're running out of options).
- Adding the style inline, both stand-alone and with !important to 100% ensure there wasn’t some other rogue style overriding.
- Changing the class name to angle-hyphen to ensure there wasn't a case sensitive issue from the database or otherwise.
- Adding the hyphen using CSS (e.g. content:"\2010")

We originally ran into the problem on a child theme of Salient which is primarily being built out using Visual Composer and the classic editor plugin.  To rule out some conflict there, we've since loaded this up in a fresh install using the base Twenty Seventeen theme and the native Guttenberg editor (which is the version you'll see in the link above).

I'm out of ideas to test.  Any suggestions are welcomed and appreciated!  Thanks in advance Stack community!

Comment: When I view your test page, the "hyphen" on it's on is actually an "–" (en dash). If I replace this with a simple "-" (hypen-minus) it displays correctly. Somewhere down the line your hyphen is being replaced.

Comment: @Turnip - Interesting.  I'm entering it in the editor with the basic "-" (hyphen-minus) next to "0" and as mentioned, have also tried adding using html code, hex, etc.  So 2 questions:  how are you distinguishing that it's showing an en dash (just for my future reference) and 2. since I tried using the html code/hex/etc - wouldn't you think that would override any sort of auto-replace with an en dash functionality that Wordpress is adding in (which seems weird to begin with).

Comment: I simply right clicked the hyphen. Chose inspect element. Then copy and pasted into this website: https://unicodelookup.com/. Perhaps these posts will be useful: https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-wordpress-handles-dashes-and-hyphens/ and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60379/how-to-prevent-automatic-conversion-of-dashes-to-ndash

Comment: Awesome.  I appreciate that.  Now that said, I just tried adding the HTML entity, hex code and HTML code to my test site (which I had already done), and I'm still seeing the same result.  Looking at your answer and @J.A. Streich answer below, would Wordpress first translate that entity/code/hex and then still replace with the en dash?

Comment: Wordpress is smart enough to know that the entity is the semantically same as the char.

Comment: Maybe you could use SVG `line`, if you don't want to deal with this in WP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/line

Comment: @Turnip - Yep.  That was absolutely it.  THANK YOU!  The working solution was rooted in the 2nd link you provided: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60379/how-to-prevent-automatic-conversion-of-dashes-to-ndash.  However, since I wanted to add that function to the child theme, I ended up pairing it with this example: https://pagecrafter.com/how-to-remove-filters-using-child-theme since the child theme's functions get read before the parent theme's.  It adds a hook and adds back the remove_filter after the parent theme's functions have loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Turnip and @J. A. Streich mention above, the problem is that by default,  Wordpress replaces the "hyphen" with an en dash.  That's apparently intended to make it easier for users to add en dashes and em dashes within written content using the editor by typing things like "--" and "---".

The solution is to remove the wptexturize filter function in functions.php.  That looks like this:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
```

However, simply adding that to functions.php has a high likelihood of being overwritten during a future update as @J.A.Streich pointed out.

If you're using a child theme to mitigate those types of overwrites, you can't just use the remove_filter option in your child theme's function.php.  Wordpress loads the child theme's functions.php first, followed by the parent theme's functions.php which means the filter won't have loaded yet when your child theme's functions runs - there's nothing for it to remove.

The solution is to hook back after the parent theme's functions.php has loaded.  You can do that in the child theme's functions.php like this:

```
function remove_parent_filters(){
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_filters' );
```

I hope that helps somebody in the future because I'd hate the amount of time I wasted on this be for nothing =).

**Update:**

While the solution above worked well for all instances of the hyphen occurring within the content of the site, it was not applying to instances found in a mega menu.  Since the menu was generated outside of "the_content", it wasn't being picked up.

I've since disabled wptexturize globally in the child theme's functions.php file.  We'll see if it holds up over time with core Wordpress updates, but it's a reasonable solution for now.

That looked like this:

```
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false', 9999 );
```

That solution, along with some insightful comments was taken from this Stack post:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241454/how-can-i-reliably-and-globally-disable-wptexturize/241468

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress turns the dash chars into en-dashes, two or three dashes into em-dashes.  Which is typically the correct thing to do typographically and symantically.  This happens when you save the post.  The replacements are done in the file `/wp-includes/formatting.php`. This is a core WordPress file, so changes to it have high probability of getting replaced on WordPress update, so keep in mind if you make this change you may have to redo it periodically.  However, the variables you'd change is `$static_characters` and it's replacement in `$static_replacements`.